# Bootstrap DatePicker - Skip array of dates in range

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, datepicker

I have a calendar with disabled days [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHFtV.png) I disable Sunday and saturday and dates before there with this properties:

```
//datesDisabled: datesForDisable, --> this is array
//daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
```

I want where i choose 18th date in **dateFrom** and 23th date in **dateTo**  get days lenght --> **2** I WANT TO SKIP DISABLED DATES

**Here i use function**

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function (startDate, endDate) {

        var disabledDates = ["13/01/2017", "19/01/2017", "20/01/2017"];
        var DisableDays = [0, 1];
        var dates = [];

        var currDate = startDate.clone().startOf('day');
        var lastDate = endDate.clone().startOf('day');

        dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());

        while (currDate.add('days', 1).diff(lastDate) < 0) {
            if (disabledDates.indexOf(moment(currDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))) == -1 && DisableDays.indexOf(currDate.day()) == -1) {
                dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());
            }
        }

        dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());

        return dates;
    };
```

Thank you previously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var DisableDays = [0, 1];
```

Defines which days of the week to be disabled.

For Disabling Saturday and Sunday use 0,6 in your disable days array.

Moment.js defines weekdays from Sunday=0 to Saturday=6 .

**Update**

Similarly for not working days compare not working array with current date in the loop.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr6jgmag/2/)

```
 if(DisableDays.indexOf(currDate.day()) == -1 && notWorkingDays.indexOf(currDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY')) == -1 )
```

-Help :)

Comment: I want to implement array of dates  to skip

Comment: in last if statement replace with new if statement ?

Comment: Yes you have to replace in the last statement as well. Please up vote the answer for others to consider it correct. Thank you :)